# Seeking example of how to tell Autofac which service to inject by name

Tags: c#, attributes, autofac, inject

I need an attribute like `[WithNamed("x")]` that will tell Autofac how to inject each 'service' with the correct parameter as shown.

The constructor to be injected with two versions of FlagXCtlr:

```
public CoupDo(
        [WithName("FLAG6")]ItemUserFlagCtrl Flag6Ctlr,
        [WithName("FLAG5")]ItemUserFlagCtrl Flag5Ctlr)
{
...
}
```

Registering is done as so:

```
builder.RegisterType<ItemUserFlagCtrl>()
       .Named<IItemUserFlagCtrl>("FLAG6")
       .WithParameter("userFlagParm", "FLAG6")
       .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<ItemUserFlagCtrl>()
       .Named<IItemUserFlagCtrl>("FLAG5")
       .WithParameter("userFlagParm", "FLAG5")
       .SingleInstance();
```

And this service's constructor is as so:

```
public ItemUserFlagCtrl(string userFlagParm)  
{
   switch (userFlagParm)   
   {
```

**Looks like it is "WithKey"!**

This looks very helpful, how do I get the "WithKey" attribute to be present?

I added these two 'using' statements shown below, to no avail. As references I have Autofac.dll, Autofac.Configuration.dll, there are two more, I will be trying next.

```
using Autofac;         
using Autofac.Features.Metadata;
```

**Error**:

```
public CouponSorter(
    [error:**WithKey**("FLAG6")]ItemUserFlagCtrl Flag6Ctlr,
    [error:**WithKey**("FLAG5")]ItemUserFlagCtrl Flag5Ctlr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says :

> **Named services are simply keyed services that use a string as a key**
>
> [Named and Keyed Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

It means that you can use the `WithKey` attribute with a string parameter to do what you want :

```
public CoupDo(
        [WithKey("FLAG6")]ItemUserFlagCtrl Flag6Ctlr,
        [WithKey("FLAG5")]ItemUserFlagCtrl Flag5Ctlr)
{
...
}
```

`WithKeyAttribute` is defined in [*Autofac.Extras.Attributed*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.Attributed) nuget package in the `Autofac.Extras.Attributed` namespace.

Another solution would be to use the `IIndex<TKey, TValue>` type

```
public CoupDo(IIndex<String, ItemUserFlagCtrl> flagControls) 
{
    ItemUserFlagCtrl flag6Ctlr = flagControls["FLAG6"]; 
    // or 
    ItemUserFlagCtrl flag6Ctlr = null; 
    if(!flagControls.TryGetValue("FLAG6"), out flag6Ctrl))
    {
        // do whatever you want if you don't have a FLAG6 named control
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: please see update above, this was very helpful, need to figure out how to get "WithKey" to be present...

Comment: the `WithKeyAttribute` is defined in Autofac.Extras.Attributed nuget package